# Is there a better way to add values in a nested array using jq?

Tags: jq

I have an array of arrays:

```json
[
  [
    "stringA",
    1
  ],
  [
    "stringA",
    2
  ],
  [
    "stringB",
    3
  ],
  [
    "stringB",
    4
  ],
  [
    "stringC",
    5
  ],
  [
    "stringC",
    6
  ]
]
```

I want to add the values where the strings match to produce:

```json
[
  [
    "stringA",
    3
  ],
  [
    "stringB",
    7
  ],
  [
    "stringC",
    11
  ]
]
```

The following jq code does this but it seems like it could be simplified:

```
group_by(.[0]) | .[] |= [.[0][0], ([.[][1]] | add)]
```

Is there a better way?

https://jqplay.org/s/wNo78mGHHe-

Comment: What you have is pretty reasonable. How would like to simplify further? Are we talking code golfing here?

Comment: If you are [afraid of numbers](https://www.fearof.net/fear-of-numbers-phobia-numerophobia-or-arithmophobia/), try `group_by(first) | map(transpose | first |= [first] | map(add))`

Comment: @Inian I suppose I was looking to see if there was a solution using existing functions that would be a bit more elegant.

Comment: @pmf This looks very neat. I didn't realise you could use `first` but the more interesting part for me is the functions you have used. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a bit more understandable:

`group_by(.[0]) | map(transpose | .[0] |= .[0] | .[1] |= add)`

Which is the equivalent to:

`group_by(first) | map(transpose | first |= first | last |= add)`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way?

Using a generic helper function can often help simplify things.
In the present case, doing so also enhances efficiency by
eliminating the use of `group_by`, which entails a sort.

#### totals/1

`totals/1` as defined here is like a bag-of-words function, but instead of counting, we accumulate the `f` values:

```
# It is assumed that the input is an array of items for which .[0] is a string
def totals(f):
  reduce .[] as $x ({};
    ($x|f) as $value
    | .[$x[0]] += $value);
```

#### unpack/0

It is also handy to have a helper function for converting
a dictionary (JSON object) to a stream of its key-value pairs:

```
def unpack: keys_unsorted[] as $k | [$k, .[$k]];
```

### Solution

```
totals(.[1]) | [unpack]
```

Answer (score 0):

By first [defining a useful group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893818/reusable-function-to-group-by-but-return-an-object-with-group-as-key):

```
def group(k):
  group_by(k) | map({key:first|k, value:.}) | from_entries;
```

The filter then becomes simply

```
group(first) | map_values(map(last)|add)
```

Which is not quite the desired output:

```json
{
  "stringA": 3,
  "stringB": 7,
  "stringC": 11
}
```

To turn that object into an array of the form `[[key, value], ...]` you need to map the entries' values:

```
group(first) | map_values(map(last)|add) | to_entries | map(map(.))
```

Output:

```json
[
  [
    "stringA",
    3
  ],
  [
    "stringB",
    7
  ],
  [
    "stringC",
    11
  ]
]
```

Of course, function can help again:

```
def to_array:
  to_entries | map(map(.));
```

And then

```
group(first) | map_values(map(last)|add) | to_array
```